# Ошибка The directory is not writable by the Web process в yii2

Tags: yii2

Команда "stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/project/frontend/web/assets" вернула 755 (мне кто-то подсказал что права должны быть такими).

Но yii2 ругается: The directory is not writable by the Web process:/var/www/project/frontend/web/assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Вот что такое права 755]

Из картинки видно, что такое права 755. Из нее же становится понятно, что Вам нужно

- либо сменить пользователя под которым запускается веб-сервер на пользователя-владельца директории и файлов
- либо дать права на "запись для группы" (если пользователь под которым запускается веб-сервер входит в ту же группу с пользователем-владельцем директории и файлов)
- либо дать права на "запись для других"